# Objective c, callback from viewController when button is clicked

Tags: ios, objective-c, callback, delegates

I have viewController1 - main view controller and viewController2 - this is my customPopUp. I want create callbacks from viewController2 when button1 or button2 is clicked.

in viewController1 code looks like this

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    CustomPopUpViewController *vc = (CustomPopUpViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomPopUpViewControllerID"];
    vc.textAlert = text;
    vc.btn1TxtAlert = btn1Txt;
    vc.isAlertOneBtn = YES;
```

i want to do something like this:

```
vc.button1Callback {

}
vc.button2Callback {

}
```

--
code in `viewController2`

`viewController2.h`

```
@interface CustomPopUpViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* titleAlert;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* textAlert;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* btn1TxtAlert;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* btn2TxtAlert;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isAlertOneBtn;
```

`viewController2.m`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    _UIbtn2Txt.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    _UIbtn2Txt.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.09 green:0.53 blue:0.00 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    
    _textLbl.text = _textAlert;
    [_UIbtn1Txt setTitle:_btn1TxtAlert forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_UIbtn2Txt setTitle:_btn2TxtAlert forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    if(_isAlertOneBtn) {
        _UIbtn2Txt.hidden = YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)btnAction1:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
       // how i can do callback from this place

}

- (IBAction)btnAction2:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
   // how i can do callback from this place

}
```

---

**i think about create in `viewController2.h` delegete methods, like this:**

```
@protocol CustomPopUpDelegate;

@interface CustomPopUpViewController : UIViewController


@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* titleAlert;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* textAlert;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* btn1TxtAlert;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString* btn2TxtAlert;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isAlertOneBtn;

@property (weak)id <CustomPopUpDelegate> delegate;
@end

@protocol CustomPopUpDelegate <NSObject >
    - (id) btn1Action;
    - (id) btn2Action;

@end
```

change on this place

```
- (IBAction)btnAction1:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
    [self.delegate btn1Action];
}

- (IBAction)btnAction2:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
    [self.delegate btn2Action];

}
```

and then **i cant understand** how i can delegate action from `btn1Action` and `btn2Action` without global implementation `CustomPopUpDelegate` in `viewController1`.

i need write callbacks from viewController2 "localy", in the same place, for example like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
        CustomPopUpViewController *vc = (CustomPopUpViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomPopUpViewControllerID"];
        vc.textAlert = text;
        vc.btn1TxtAlert = btn1Txt;
        vc.isAlertOneBtn = YES;
    vc.button1Callback {
// how write like this??    
    }
    vc.button2Callback {
    // how write like this??    

    }
```

Comment: Use blocks ... in vc2, have two ivars ```@property (nonatomic,strong) void ( ^ action1 )( void );``` or whatever you need and then set them from vc1 and execute them in vc2.

Comment: @skaak thanks for the answer, but can you please explain more, its not clear for me. For example in vc2 i made `@property (nonatomic, strong) void ( ^ action1 )( void );` then in vc2 i call method `[self action1];` if a button was clicked. In the vc1 i tried to create callback like this `[vc action1:^ {}]` but it seems something wrong(

Comment: Ok, I'll post as answer as I need more space, but blocks are the man for this job ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocks is what you use here. They are, you could say, made for this.

Create an ivar where you want the callback. Now the callback is a block, a piece of code that you will execute when needed. So the type of block will vary depending on that. Here are some examples ...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) void ( ^ callbackAction1 )( BOOL ); // Block is named callbackAction1 - it takes a BOOL arg and returns nothing
@property (nonatomic, strong) BOOL ( ^ callbackAction2 )( BOOL ); // Block is named callbackAction2 - it takes a BOOL and returns a BOOL
@property (nonatomic, strong) void ( ^ callbackAction3 )( void ); // Block is named callbackAction3 - it takes nothing and returns nothing

// Real life example
@property (nonatomic,strong)    void ( ^ valueChanged )( XXBooleanCollectionViewCell *, BOOL );
```

... and so on.

Then you link these blocks to your actions, e.g. in your case

```
- (IBAction)btnAction1:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
    if ( self.callbackAction1 ) {
       // Here we use the block
       self.callbackAction1 ( YES ); // or whatever you need ...
    }
}
```

Sometimes if the UI requires it you could execute the block in the completion block and if the completion block is of the correct format, you could even pass the block as the completion block, thus

```
- (IBAction)btnAction1:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:callbackAction3];
}
```

and this will call callbackAction3 when done.

Then, to call it 'locally' as you call it, change your code as in the example below.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
        CustomPopUpViewController *vc = (CustomPopUpViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CustomPopUpViewControllerID"];
        vc.textAlert = text;
        vc.btn1TxtAlert = btn1Txt;
        vc.isAlertOneBtn = YES;
    vc.button1Callback {
// how write like this??    
    }
    vc.button2Callback {
    // how write like this??    

    }
    // This is how
    vc.callbackAction1 = ^ ( BOOL p ) { 
       if ( p ) something ... the logic of the callback goes in here
    };
    vc.callbackAction2 = ^ BOOL { ... callback logic ... };
    vc.callbackAction3 = ^ { ... };
```

This is a common pattern for this type of thing. I am not entirely clear on your logic and my response may not work exactly so let me know and I'll update accordingly, but this is the man for the job.

Based on your comment, I think you got the syntax wrong and it should be

```
vc.action1 = ^{ ... };
```

Here is a nice site once you get stuck in the syntax http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/.

Comment: Was nice - Im sure this has been asked before but your code is begging for blocks and it was nice an' easy to just insert the pieces in the correct places in your code. But again, maybe I got it wrong somewhere so let me know then and I'll fix it up ...

Comment: Great stuff - you were thinking the right way, I can see that in your code, you just lacked the technique. Now you know it - it is great and used a lot, e.g. all those completion handlers. Sometimes you'd use a delegate as well but that is a bit heavy - blocks are nice and lightweight. Thanks